# Azure DevOps uzip as a deploy task

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, zip

does anyone know how to uznip a file as a part of the deployment pipeline?

At the moment deploy finishes with a zip archive inside of fronted/download/myfiles.zip.

I want to add a task which will take this zip file and extract it into e.g.
frontend/download/archive/...

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an Extract Archive task provided by Microsoft that you can use to extract archived files.

After you added it as a task that runs on your deployment group to you can configure it so that it does what you need. Make sure to set *Archive file patterns* and *Destination folder* correctly.

[image: Add Extract Files task]
[image: Configure task to extract from and where you want to]

Comment: Thank you Felix, I saw that extension but I struggle how to pick up the file and where to extract it.

Or to re phrase how to define inside Archive parameters [root of the deployed website]/app/my.zip file

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has provided a [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops) for this, but i would like to share some info related to yaml snippet

```
steps:
 - task: ExtractFiles@1
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: 'QtBinaries.rar'
    destinationFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\bin'
    cleanDestinationFolder: false
- task: ExtractFiles@1
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: 'AzureNeededDlls.rar'
    destinationFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\bin'
    cleanDestinationFolder: false
```

Here i am trying to extract the two rar files with names('QtBinaries.rar, AzureNeededDlls.rar'), we can do it as one task also it depends on need.